# C++/CLI StreamReader - Elegant Way To Check Last Characters

Tags: file, c++-cli, streamreader, uart

I'm currently reading in a text file and sending it over the UART as follows:

```
System::IO::StreamReader^ sr = gcnew
    System::IO::StreamReader(filename);
try {
    serialport->Write(sr->ReadToEnd());
} catch (TimeoutException^ e) {
    ...
} catch (InvalidOperationException^ e) {
    ...
}
sr->Close();
```

What I would like to do is modify this code so that if and only if the file did not end in a carriage return (\r\n), it will send one over the UART.

As far as I can tell, I already read to the end of the file and StreamReader can't read backwards.

Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to do something more complex with the file and break my clean elegant approach?

Comment: So it can't be done using StreamReader? There's no way to just peak at the last 2 bytes of a StreamReader? The best approach in this case is to abandon StreamReader altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Elegant is in the eye of the beholder, reading the entire content of the file in memory first is not elegant.  The code is also not exception-safe, you'll want to google "c++/cli stack semantics" to learn how to avoid writing code like this.

Just read the file line-by-line so you don't care at all what the line-endings look like:

```
  for each (auto line in System::IO::File::ReadLines(filename)) serialport->WriteLine(line);
```